# Userform listbox data not showing but seems to be in listbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a search form which shows a listbox of results. It starts empty and when I conduct a search then rows are created but no data is visible.

I checked a few obvious things like color and all seem normal black font etc. If I have the worksheet with the sourcedata in view the data in the list is visible, but in everyday practice that would not be the case. I think it is conducting the search on the correct results but then displaying the equivalent rows from another worksheet.

[image: Invisible listbox data]

My userform code. I assume the problem is where it is calling the Results range. I tried adding a worksheet reference of the source data to the start of Range.Records and that doesn't help:

```vb
Option Explicit

' Display All Matches from Search in Userform ListBox
'
Dim FormEvents As Boolean

Private Sub ClearForm(Except As String)

' Clears the list box and text boxes EXCEPT the text box
' currently having data entered into it

    Select Case Except
    
        Case "srchStCat"
            FormEvents = False
            srchStID.Value = ""
            srchStSurname.Value = ""
            Results.Clear
            FormEvents = True

        Case "srchStID"
            FormEvents = False
            srchStCat.Value = ""
            srchStSurname.Value = ""
            Results.Clear
            FormEvents = True

        Case "srchStSurname"
            FormEvents = False
            srchStID.Value = ""
            srchStCat.Value = ""
            Results.Clear
            FormEvents = True
       
        Case Else
            FormEvents = False
            srchStCat.Value = ""
            srchStID.Value = ""
            srchStSurname.Value = ""
            Results.Clear
            FormEvents = True
            
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub CmdClear_Click()
    ClearForm ("")
End Sub

Private Sub CmdClose_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub srchStCat_Change()
    If FormEvents Then ClearForm ("srchStCat")
End Sub

Private Sub srchStID_Change()
    If FormEvents Then ClearForm ("srchStID")
End Sub

Private Sub srchStSurname_Change()
    If FormEvents Then ClearForm ("srchStSurname")
End Sub

Private Sub CmdSearch_Click()
    Dim SearchTerm As String
    Dim SearchColumn As String
    Dim RecordRange As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim FirstCell As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    
    ' Display an error if no search term is entered
    If srchStCat.Value = "" And srchStID.Value = "" And srchStSurname.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "No search term specified", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Work out what is being searched for
    If srchStCat.Value <> "" Then
        SearchTerm = srchStCat.Value
        SearchColumn = "Current Role"
    End If
    
    If srchStID.Value <> "" Then
        SearchTerm = srchStID.Value
        SearchColumn = "ID Token" 
    End If

    If srchStSurname.Value <> "" Then
        SearchTerm = srchStSurname.Value
        SearchColumn = "Surname"
    End If

    Results.Clear
    
    ' Only search in the relevant table column i.e. if somone is searching srchStSurname
    ' only search in the srchStSurname column
    With Worksheets("Staff").Range("StaffFullData[" & SearchColumn & "]")

        ' Find the first match
        Set RecordRange = .Find(SearchTerm, LookIn:=xlValues)

        ' If a match has been found
        If Not RecordRange Is Nothing Then

            FirstAddress = RecordRange.Address
            RowCount = 0

            Do
                
                ' Set the first cell in the row of the matching value
                Set FirstCell = Range("A" & RecordRange.Row)
                    
                ' Add matching record to List Box
                Results.AddItem
                Results.List(RowCount, 0) = FirstCell(1, 2)
                Results.List(RowCount, 1) = FirstCell(1, 7)
                Results.List(RowCount, 2) = FirstCell(1, 5)
                Results.List(RowCount, 3) = FirstCell(1, 18)

                RowCount = RowCount + 1
                    
                ' Look for next match
                Set RecordRange = .FindNext(RecordRange)

                ' When no further matches are found, exit the sub
                If RecordRange Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                ' Keep looking while unique matches are found
            Loop While RecordRange.Address <> FirstAddress

        Else
            
            ' If you get here, no matches were found
            Results.AddItem
            Results.List(RowCount, 0) = "Nothing Found"
            
        End If

    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    FormEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Results_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim i As Long
With Me.Results
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            Me.TextBoxGetStaffFName.Value = .List(i, 1)
            Me.TextBoxGetStaffSurname.Value = .List(i, 2)
            Me.TextBoxGetStaffID.Value = .List(i, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok just figured out I need to specify the sheet in two places not just one. I needed to edit this section where asterixed

```
    *With Sheet11.Range("StaffFullData[" & SearchColumn & "]")*

            ' Find the first match
            Set RecordRange = .Find(SearchTerm, LookIn:=xlValues)

            ' If a match has been found
            If Not RecordRange Is Nothing Then

                *FirstAddress = Sheet11.RecordRange.Address*
```

Comment: You need to specify the sheet here: `Set FirstCell = Range("A" & RecordRange.Row)`

Comment: Yoo,
Could you please share what did you do to solve this.
Same issue with me, if the sheet is visible then list is loading but if the sheet is hidden the data is not visible, but the list shows white spaces
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:
Use
**Range.Address(,,,1)** to get the full address